# KQL Search in Timer Job, quote error

Tags: c#, search, sharepoint, quote

I'm working on a Timer Job which has to search all SharePoint contents with a specified property value. If this property contain a quote, the request fail and otherwise without this caracter, everthing works as expected. I tried to replace the quote by a backquote (`) but this works only in an application console.

KQL Query example :

```
ThematiqueEnrichment="Vie de l'administration" --> fail

ThematiqueEnrichment="toto" --> works
```

Somebody has an idea about this problem ? and why the backquote doesn't works only in a Timer Job

Thank's for your help

```
KeywordQuery kq = new KeywordQuery(_site);
kq.QueryText = "ContentTypeId:0x01010006DC43FAAA7D45E8AF6C31AE603C9BA5006CFA76F0311643E58860A89C066A5C6F*) AND ThematiqueEnrichment=\"" + currentSource.DisplayName + "\" ";
kq.SelectProperties.Clear();
kq.SelectProperties.Add("PublishingPageContentOWSHTML");
kq.SelectProperties.Add("EMSTotemsDatePublicationOWSDATEFormat");
kq.SortList.Add("EMSTotemsDatePublicationOWSDATEFormat", SortDirection.Descending);
ResultTableCollection resultTableCollection = new SearchExecutor().ExecuteQuery(kq);
ResultTable resultTable = resultTableCollection.Filter("TableType", KnownTableTypes.RelevantResults).FirstOrDefault();
if (resultTable != null)
{
   foreach (DataRow row in resultTable.Table.Rows)
   { 
    // Manage items
   }
}
```

Comment: Please show us some code.

Comment: I added it in the description ;)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I have a SharePoint in English with a french language pack. 
 So I needed to set my cultureInfo in French to allow the Query to manage the quote.

In my console the Culture was in french and in the Timer Job in English. This explain why the comportment was different.

```
KeywordQuery kq = new KeywordQuery(_site);
kq.QueryText = "ContentTypeId:0x01010006DC43FAAA7D45E8AF6C31AE603C9BA5006CFA76F0311643E58860A89C066A5C6F*) AND ThematiqueEnrichment=\"" + currentSource.DisplayName + "\" ";
kq.SelectProperties.Clear();
kq.Culture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
```